# How to execute code on Jupyter Notebook when opening it

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I don't know if it's possible but I would like to execute Python code inside my Jupyter notebook when opening it.

I know that I can go to Cell >> Run All, but what I am looking for is a way to automatically do it.

Comment: Are you needing to run all the code? Or just some of it? You can also run all the code in it from the command line using [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-from-the-command-line) or [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill) so that when you open the result, the executed notebook is what you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you have nbextensions installed, you can designate "initialization cells", which run when the notebook is run. You define them using the `cell` -> `cell type` options from the menu.

2) Javascript:

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
display(Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells_below()"))
```

3) For full autonomy from cells you can always import your python code, replacing 
   cell boundries with function calls.

Comment: So, what exactly should I seed under ```cell -> cell type```? I installed nbexensions following this link but I only see three options: Code, Markdown, Raw NBConvert. https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#conda

Comment: You should see 'initialization cell' in addition to the other three.  Try restarting the kernel...

Comment: ... and don't forget to check the 'initialization cells' bot in the nbextensions tab.

Comment: You probably need to mark the notebook as trusted, too?

Comment: Per @Wayne's comment, If you use the Javascript approach, expect trust issues.

Answer (score -2):

In Jupyter you have to run the code cell by cell,
another shortcut is SHift+Enter to run.

If you want to run all the codes in same time you can copy it to SPyder and run.